# How many different ﬂush hands can you have that consist only of hearts, diamonds or spades?

Tags: combinatorics, poker

In poker, a ﬂush is a 5-card hand where all the cards have the same suit. Recall that a deck of cards has 52
cards. There are 4 suits (hearts, clubs, diamonds and spades) and each suit has 13 cards.

> How many ways can you get a flush of hearts, diamonds or spades?

For this question, I am thinking the answer is 13C5+13C5+13C5 where C is choses.I am not so sure because it looks tricky

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: When asking questions, it is a good idea to put the entire question in the body, rather than split it between the body and the title.

Comment: It's not so easy.It would depend on pre -flop cards and the 5 cards from deck on table. Also the no. of players will distribute cards among themselves.

Comment: @exploringnet you only want to know all different ways to obtain a flush, not a probability or something, so the no. of players are irrelevant. And you don't know what kind of poker it is. Could be 5 hand, or 2 hand with 5 open card so maybe there isnt a flop..

Comment: @Bob Ok , then you would like to solve a irrelevant question without details?

Comment: @exploringnet I dont see the problem here. The question is clear. You take 5 cards, what is the number of possibilities to get a flush of diamonds, spades or harts.

Comment: Then Poker must not be included.It would be fine then , a straight forward question of $P_nC$

Comment: Seems to be the case, I think, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as you wrote: $13\choose5$ counts the number of different ways to get 5 cards out of that particular suit. This is the same for any suit, and so if you're interested in those particular flushes, the answer is as you gave: $3\cdot {13\choose 5}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed $_{13}C_5$ ways to have a flush hand of any given suit, and flushes of different suits are mutually exclusive events. Thus, just adding them up (as you did) works fine!

Answer (score 1):

That's it =)

So $$3 \cdot {13 \choose 5}$$

Comment: Even this could have been a comment and even have solved the problem to end in comments only.

Comment: It's at least the right answer + confirmation for OP. But I wasn't trying to start a tug-o-war, so get over it. A question needs an answer, people provide answers and don't give a half-relevant answer if they know what correct answer is. That's my view.

Comment: @exploringnet downvoting, now that's mature :')

Answer (score 0):

♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥

The total no of flushes possible are:$4\times ^{13}C_5$ and the favourable are $3\times^{13}C_4$
Chance for flush:

[image]
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_rankings#Flush

Comment: @Manuel For good discussion Post this on poker.SE

Comment: 1. this is for a flush of any suit, 2. a straight flush is still a flush, 3. its the chance you get a flush, not the number of different flushes

Comment: We both know that, but as this was the question, you maybe should give that as an answer then, or dont give an answer as above at all. You could post it as a comment maybe if you want to make this clear.

Comment: Not only we both but also the OP knows it. and You are no one to ask me to do so.If you feel so,I'd like to say: even you have not  got stars down for him in your answer.

Comment: Ok, if you really consider the above answer a relevant... And I'm not asking anything from you, you could see it as a tip. I actually dont mind what you do with it afterwards :)